# how to count items in an order(when item status=Mixed) using orderid in magento?

Tags: magento

I am trying to count total number of items in an order but I am unable to do so correctly.
I am using this code -

```
$total=0;
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($oid);
$items = $order->getAllItems();

foreach($items as $item){
$qty = $item->getQtyToInvoice();
$total = $total + $qty;
}
echo "total :".$total;
```

This print correct result if the items status in orders  is shipped but if the item status is mixed ,it prints 0 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you simply looking for the number of items ordered, regardless of its shipped/invoiced/refunded status?

If so then then replace `getQtyToInvoice()` with `getQtyOrdered()`.

For example:

```
foreach($items as $item){
    $qty = $item->getQtyOrdered();
}
```

To answer the question in the comments: "I am also looking for the number of items shipped"

```
$item->getQtyShipped()
```

Comment: I am also looking for the number of items shipped. how to calculate those?

Comment: Okay ,I'll try it .
A quick question,Can you tell me why the  item status is showing mixed.What's the meaning of mixed ?Thank You

Comment: Have a look in Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Item - at the top of the class you can see all of the constants which define the order statuses - mixed is essentially any combination that is not defined.  A kind of fallback/default status

Comment: Thank You for your response. If its not a "good" status ,Why all my previous completed orders have mixed item status.I wonder!

Comment: That's really out of the scope of this question and most likely something you will need to look at in depth if its an issue to you - As a starting point for you to investigate, look at the getStatusId() method in Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Item - you will see the logic of how the status id is being determined.  If you have further, specific issues you may want to post another question.  Please remember to mark this question as correct/upvote if it has helped the original issue.  Thanks again :)

Comment: Yea ,Sure I'll accept your answer if it helped me in solving the problem.